# Does Firebase encrypt the token before saving it in AsyncStorage?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, asyncstorage

I understand that for persistence login Firebase uses asyncstorage to store the token. What I don't understand is why as it's clearly mentioned that asyncstorage is **not** encrypted and should not be used for token storage: https://reactnative.dev/docs/security

```
export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
```

Edit: I am using Firebase Javascript sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#auth_package
not RNfirebase

Comment: What I really think you have here is feedback for the developers of the [React Native Firebase libraries](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) that implement this. The decision they made might not even have a clear reason, or perhaps predates the availability of more secure options.

Comment: i could not find the article so currect me @DougStevenson if i am wrong, but some where i read that the firebase's authentication system encrypts the token before storing it in AsyncStorage so this encryption adds an extra layer of security that will remove the any risks associated with use of AsyncStorage for token storage. so i think it is ok and you can trust firebase's implementation to handle token storage securely.